# Partial dependency injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

In a MVC context, I have a controller that depends on a service, the service in turn depends on a data_source (in the specific case, a client to fetch data from a third-party API).

In order to instantiate the service with a mock data_source when testing, the service's constructor expects a data_source. 
The same holds for the controller, whose constructor expects a service.

When creating a controller, I want to pass it a request object as well, because I'd prefer this

`new Controller(request, service).action_name`

to this

`new Controller(service).action_name(request)`

Achieving this without using any container for Dependency Injection is trivial.

What I don't understand is how to do so using [php-di](http://php-di.org/)

My objective is to have the service injected into the controller by the container, while passing the request object to the controller myself.

**UPDATE 1**

This is my ApplicationController

```
namespace DEC;


class ApplicationController {

    private $service;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Foo $service, $request) {
        $this->service= $service;
        $this->request = $request;
    }


    public function index() {
        $out = $this->service->foo();
        $out .= $this->request->method();
        return $out;
    }

}
```

Foo follows

```
namespace DEC;

class Foo {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function foo() {
        return "FOO";
    }
}
```

This my Request

```
namespace DEC;

class Foo {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function foo() {
        return "FOO";
    }
}
```

And this is my attempt to get DI to work as I'd like:

```
$container = ContainerBuilder::buildDevContainer();
$response = $container->call([ApplicationController::class, 'index'], [
            'request' => new Request('GET')
]);
echo $response;
```

This is the error I get:

```
Entry "DEC\ApplicationController" cannot be resolved: Parameter $request of __construct() has no value defined or guessable
Full definition:
Object (
    class = DEC\ApplicationController
    scope = singleton
    lazy = false
    __construct(
        $service = get(DEC\Foo)
        $request = #UNDEFINED#
    )
)
```

**N.B.: the error stays the same if I type-hint the request and/or switch the order of params in the constructor**

Looking at the error, I infer that the ::call() solution proposed by Matthew Napoli works if I instantiate the controller with just the service and pass the request as a parameter for the action method.

Does this mean that I can't rely on the container for "partial" injection?

**UPDATE 2**

For the solution described in this update, please look at my own answer to the question

Comment: Any reason you want to use php-di? It does use reflection(slow). You just going to add some 3rd party "black magic" to your project. How much typing you actually going to save? Just my IMHO.

Comment: @E_p there is no performance penalty, everything is cached. If *you* don't like reflection, you can also disable it: http://php-di.org/doc/autowiring.html#configuration

Comment: My codebase being small, I don't expect measurable performance issues.
I picked php-di, because it has almost 1K subscribers on GitHub and is actively maintained

Comment: https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by setting my request in the container before asking for a controller:

```
$container->set('DEC\Request', new Request('GET'));
$controller = $container->get('DEC\ApplicationController');
$response = $controller->index();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you have tried, but this should call the action method and pass it the request (and resolve the controller with all its dependencies):

```
$container->call([MyController::class, 'action_name'], [
    'request' => $request,
]);
```

Read more about `call()` here: http://php-di.org/doc/container.html#call

Answer (score 0):

**About request:**

Do not type-hint the $request parameter:

```
public function __construct($request, /*...*/) {}
```

Or type-hint a RequestInterface for it:

```
public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, /*...*/) {}
```

In both cases the DIC will not be able to automatically create a request instance. You can then inject it yourself.

**About Service:**

Type-hint it with a concrete, like "Service". Then a service instance will be automatically created by the DIC, with all of its dependencies (data_source).

Or type-hint it with an interface, like "ServiceInterface", and set an entry for it in the DIC, using an alias in the PHP definitions. Something like this:

```
return [
    'ServiceInterface' => DI\get('<NAMESPACE-TO>\Service'),
];
```

See:

PHP-DI "Limitations" at http://php-di.org/doc/autowiring.html#limitations

PHP-DI "PHP definitions - Aliases" at http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#aliases

Hope this helped.